# Rails Installer C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `kill': Invalid argument (Errno::EINVAL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, railsinstaller

I am using Windows 7.

I downloaded and ran the rails installer "railsinstaller-2.2.5.exe"

Then I followed the https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88 for 'SSL upgrades on rubygems.org and RubyInstaller versions'

```
D:\Projects\AptanaWorkspace\cms_synth>rails --version
Rails 4.1.1

D:\Projects\AptanaWorkspace\cms_synth>ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
```

Then tried and received

```
D:\Projects\AptanaWorkspace\cms_synth>rails s
    => Booting WEBrick
    => Rails 4.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
    => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0
    .0.1 (--binding option)
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    Exiting


C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in 

`kill': Invalid argument (Errno::EINVAL)


from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-   1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `pidfile_process_status'
                from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:340:in `check_pid!'
                from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:246:in `start'
                from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
                from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
                from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
                from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
                from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
                from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
                from bin/rails:4:in `require'
                from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

My Gem List:

```
D:\Projects\AptanaWorkspace\cms_synth>gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

    actionmailer (4.1.1, 3.2.21)
    actionpack (4.1.1, 3.2.21)
    actionview (4.1.1)
    activemodel (4.1.8, 4.1.1, 3.2.21)
    activerecord (4.1.8, 4.1.1, 3.2.21)
    activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.1.0)
    activeresource (3.2.21)
    activesupport (4.1.8, 4.1.1, 3.2.21)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214, 3.0.3)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2 x86-mingw32)
    bigdecimal (1.1.0)
    bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.0)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.9)
    builder (3.2.2, 3.0.4)
    bundler (1.7.7)
    capybara (2.1.0)
    childprocess (0.5.5)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1, 3.2.2)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
    coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
    cucumber (1.3.17)
    cucumber-rails (1.4.0)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.2.2)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
    faker (1.1.2)
    ffi (1.9.6 x86-mingw32)
    gherkin (2.12.2 x86-mingw32)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.7.0, 0.6.11)
    io-console (0.3)
    jbuilder (2.2.6)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (3.1.2, 1.0.19)
    json (1.8.1, 1.5.5)
    mail (2.5.4)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.1)
    minitest (5.5.0, 5.4.3, 2.5.1)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    multi_test (0.1.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.5 x86-mingw32)
    pg (0.17.1 x86-mingw32)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
    rack-ssl (1.3.4)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
    rails (4.1.1, 3.2.21)
    railties (4.1.1, 3.2.21)
    rake (10.4.2, 10.4.0, 0.9.2.2)
    rb-notifu (0.0.4)
    rb-readline (0.5.1)
    rdoc (4.2.0, 3.9.5)
    rspec-core (2.13.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
    rspec-rails (2.13.1)
    rubyzip (1.1.6, 0.9.9)
    sass (3.4.9, 3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.5, 3.2.6)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
    selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
    shoulda-matchers (2.7.0)
    sprockets (2.11.0, 2.2.3)
    sprockets-rails (2.2.2)
    sqlite3 (1.3.10 x86-mingw32, 1.3.8 x86-mingw32)
    sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    tiny_tds (0.6.2 x86-mingw32)
    treetop (1.4.15)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
    tzinfo (1.2.2, 0.3.42)
    tzinfo-data (1.2014.10)
    uglifier (2.6.0)
    wdm (0.1.0)
    websocket (1.0.7)
    will_paginate (3.0.4)
    xpath (2.0.0)
```

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So the gripe seems to be around the location of the PID file, which doesn't make a lot of sense, but you're also not running rails in the context of your install.

Try this and see what it does:

> bundle exec rails s

Answer (score 0):

From the hint of Jason Mcmunn I could find a way. The problem was solved by deleting the \tmp\pids\pids\server.pid file. Thanks.